# Javascript indexOf and replace - am I missing something

Tags: javascript, function, indexof

I have this javascript function; 
i send it a number from a button and all go well untill the index-of method it has a problem.

CODE:

```
   <script lang="ja" type="text/javascript">


    function YellowChair(NumId)
    {
        if (document.getElementById("CheckBox" + NumId).checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("ChairImg" + NumId).src = "Images/YellowChair.png";
            TypeTheNum(NumId, true);
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("ChairImg" + NumId).src = "Images/BlueChair.png";
            TypeTheNum(NumId, false);
        }

    }
    function TypeTheNum(NumId,Add)
    {
        var Label = document.getElementById("SelectedSitsLabel");
        var Hidden = document.getElementById("SelectedSitsHidden");


        if (Label.innerHTML == "")
        {
            Label.textContent += NumId;
            Hidden.textContent += NumId;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Add)
            {
                Label.textContent += "," + NumId;
            }
            else
            {
         // getting stuck here.
                if (Label.indexOf((NumId + ",").toString()) != -1)
                {
                    alert("1");
                    Label.replace((NumId + ",").toString(), "");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("ELSE");
                    Label.replace(("," + NumId).toString(), "");
                }
            }
        }
        Hidden.textContent = Label.textContent;
    }


</script>
```

i thought maybe its because I insert text with textContent,
also , im pretty sure somthing is wrong with the `replace`.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTMLElement` hasn't a method indexOf.`String` owned the method.remeber reset `textContent` if the `textContent` changed.

```js
    function YellowChair(NumId)
    {
        if (document.getElementById("CheckBox" + NumId).checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("ChairImg" + NumId).src = "Images/YellowChair.png";
            TypeTheNum(NumId, true);
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("ChairImg" + NumId).src = "Images/BlueChair.png";
            TypeTheNum(NumId, false);
        }

    }
    function TypeTheNum(NumId,Add)
    {
        var Label = document.getElementById("SelectedSitsLabel");
        var Hidden = document.getElementById("SelectedSitsHidden");


        if (Label.innerHTML == "")
        {
            Label.textContent += NumId;
            Hidden.textContent += NumId;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Add)
            {
                Label.textContent += "," + NumId;
            }
            else
            {
         // getting stuck here.
                if (Label.textContent.indexOf((NumId + ",").toString()) != -1)
                {
                    alert("1");
                    Label.textContent=Label.textContent.replace((NumId + ",").toString(), "");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("ELSE");
                    Label.textContent=Label.textContent.replace(("," + NumId).toString(), "");
                }
            }
        }
        Hidden.textContent = Label.textContent;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="TypeTheNum('foo')">Remove `foo`</button>
<div id="SelectedSitsLabel">foo,bar,baz</div>
<div id="SelectedSitsHidden"></div>
```

Comment: Simlarly `indexOf`,the `HTMLElement` has no method `replace`,but the `String` has.

Answer (score 1):

The function:

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
```

Returns an **Element** object, or null but not an string.

Maybe you want to change your code to use `textContent` property which seems to be the one you are working on like:

```
if (Label.textContent.indexOf((NumId + ",").toString()) != -1){
   alert("1");
   Label.textContent.replace((NumId + ",").toString(), "");
}
else{
   alert("ELSE");
   Label.textContent.replace(("," + NumId).toString(), "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Label is a DOM element, not a string. So if you need to get characters from the text inside the element, you have to use something like `var content = Label.textContent; content.indexOf()` and then replace the textContent again after replacing it in the string.

Also as a sidenote, try to look up the differences between innerHTML, textContent and innerText so you can avoid future issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the replacement to something:

`Label.textContent = Label.textContent.replace(…)`